# C++ Sort a vector of pointers in which the objects represent matrix coordinates

Tags: c++, sorting, matrix, vector

I read a file in which a matrix is filled with 0, 1 and 2. 
When I find a 1 I create a BlueCar, when 2 I create RedCar:

```
class BlueCar : public Car
{
    public:
        BlueCar(){};
        BlueCar(int x, int y);
        void move();
        virtual ~BlueCar();
};
```

---

```
class RedCar : public Car
{
    public:
        RedCar(){};
        RedCar(int x, int y);
        void move();
        virtual ~RedCar();
};
```

---

```
class Car
{
    public:
        Car();
        Car(int x, int y);
        virtual ~Car();
        virtual void move() = 0;

    private:
        int x,y;
};
```

With this objects I fill two vectors:

```
    std::vector<BluCar*> *sparseBlu;
    std::vector<RedCar*> *sparseRed;
```

Considering that I need to move the cars of the matrix, and that Blue ones move downward and Red ones move rightward, I think the best approach is to sort this vectors. In that way I can see quickly if the position next to the car I'm considering is empty.

Since Blue cars move downward I think it's better to sort "sparseBlu" first by column and then by row, instead "sparseRed" first by row and then by column.

How can I achieve this result?
It's better (in terms of performance) to sort the vector immediately when I fill it car by car, right?

Comment: First, why store pointers in the vector?  `std::vector<BluCar>`, `std::vector<RedCar>`.  And why are the vectors pointers themselves?  `std::vector<BluCar> sparsBlu`, `std::vector<RedCar> sparsRed`.

Comment: what's happen when 2 cars go to the same coordinate ?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie because I don't know if the size of the matrix will be for ex. 10x10 or 100000x100000, so I don't want to fill al the stack.

Comment: @Jarod42 they can't go to the same coordinate because there is a turn for the red cars and a turn for blu cars

Comment: @rh0x A `std::vector` uses the heap, not stack, to allocate data.  Where did you get the idea that a std::vector uses the stack?  A `std::array<T>` uses stack based elements, not a vector.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie so if I declare std::vector<BlueCar> sparseBlue all the cars are allocated on the heap?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you are studying object orientation, then you are doing it wrong, as nothing is polymorphic here. You should create a sparse matrix of `Car*` (or better use a smart pointer), not two separate matrices with `BlueCar`s and `RedCar`s. If you want highest perfirmance possible, forget about objects altogether. 0, 1 and 2 of the original data is all you need.

Comment: @n.m. probably I'm using the wrong data structure, so the first thing I have to solve is to choose a better solution for this. I'll ask a new question and I'll post the link here.

Comment: The question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591861/c-efficient-time-and-space-complexity-data-structure-for-dense-and-sparse-m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

```
std::sort(std::begin(*sparseBlu), std::end(*sparseBlu),
          [](const BlueCar* lhs, const BlueCar* rhs) -> bool {
              return lhs->get_x() < rhs->get_x() ||
                     (lhs->get_x() == rhs->get_x() && lhs->get_y() < rhs->get_y());
          });

std::sort(std::begin(*sparseRed), std::end(*sparseRed),
          [](const RedCar* lhs, const RedCar* rhs) -> bool {
              return lhs->get_y() < rhs->get_y() ||
                     (lhs->get_y() == rhs->get_y() && lhs->get_x() < rhs->get_x());
          });
```

Please reconsider, if using pointers really is what you need here. Without pointers you have less noise.

```
std::vector<BluCar> sparseBlu;
std::vector<RedCar> sparseRed;

std::sort(std::begin(sparseBlu), std::end(sparseBlu),
          [](const BlueCar& lhs, const BlueCar& rhs) -> bool {
              return lhs.get_x() < rhs.get_x() ||
                     (lhs.get_x() == rhs.get_x() && lhs.get_y() < rhs.get_y());
          });

std::sort(std::begin(sparseRed), std::end(sparseRed),
          [](const RedCar& lhs, const RedCar& rhs) -> bool {
              return lhs.get_y() < rhs.get_y() ||
                     (lhs.get_y() == rhs.get_y() && lhs.get_x() < rhs.get_x());
          });
```

When that kind of ordering is natural in your application you might also consider to overload `operator < ()`. That makes the calls to `sort()` much more explicit:

```
std::sort(std::begin(sparseBlu), std::end(sparseBlu), std::less<BlueCar>);
std::sort(std::begin(sparseRed), std::end(sparseRed), std::less<RedCar>);
```

An almost declarative programming style.

If you decide to stick with pointers for whatever reason, please consider to use `std::unique_ptr<>` or `std::shared_ptr<>` instead of raw pointers, to manage the objects lifetime correctly. Remember, that there is no garbage collection in C++.

Comment: For your comparison method, you may use: `return std::make_tuple(lhs.get_x(), lhs.get_y()) < std::make_tuple(rhs.get_x(), rhs.get_y());`

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, thanks. I am just a bit worried, that comparing tuples might not clearly enough state the intent here. It might be surprising to readers of the code. As an implementation of `operator < ()` I'd appreciate your approach.

Comment: @cdonat mmm...I think I didn't understand how vectors work, so I don't need pointers

Answer (score 0):

`std::sort` has an overloaded version with a comparator - a custom function to compare two items: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort, so you can specify any comparison.

Also you can consider storing your cars in a sparse matrix (`std::vector<std::vector<Car>>`) where empty cells are just empty. So you don't need to sort and can just look at corresponding cell if it's empty.

Comment: I don't understand the second part in which you say to use std::vector<std::vector<Car>>.... How can I have an empty cell?

Comment: You can't.  What's more, the matrix wouldn't hold `BlueCar`s or `RedCar`s - just `Car`s.  This *is* a case for pointers.  If you had a dense matrix `std::vector<std::vector<Car*>>` you could hold the cars polymorphically, and have empty cells.

Comment: Raw pointers:  With the lifetimes managed elsewhere.  If this is going to manage the lifetimes, then `std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Car>>>`