# Efficient (time and space complexity) data structure for dense and sparse matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, vector

I have to read a file in which is stored a matrix with cars (*1=BlueCar, 2=RedCar, 0=Empty*).

I need to **write an algorithm to move the cars** of the matrix in that way:

- blue ones move *downward*;
- red ones move *rightward*;
- there is a *turn* in which all the blue ones move and a turn to move all the red ones.

Before the file is read I don't know the matrix size and if it's dense or sparse, so I have to implement **two data structures** (one for dense and one for sparse) and two algorithms.

I need to reach the **best time and space complexity possible**.

Due to the unknown matrix size, I think to store the data on the heap.

If the matrix is **dense**, I think to use something like:

```
short int** M = new short int*[m];
short int*  M_data = new short int[m*n];

for(int i=0; i< m; ++i) 
{
    M[i] = M_data + i * n;
}
```

With this structure I can allocate a contiguous space of memory and it is also simple to be accessed with `M[i][j]`.

Now the problem is the structure to choose for the **sparse** case, and I have to consider also how I can move the cars through the algorithm in the simplest way: for example when I evaluate a car, I need to find easily if in the next position (downward or rightward) there is another car or if it's empty.

Initially I thought to define BlueCar and RedCar objects that inherits from the general Car object. In this objects I can save the matrix coordinates and then put them in:

```
std::vector<BluCar> sparseBlu;
std::vector<RedCar> sparseRed;
```

Otherwise I can do something like:

```
vector< tuple< row, column, value >> sparseMatrix
```

But the problem of finding what's in the next position still remains.

Probably this is not the best way to do it, so how can I implement the sparse case in a efficient way? (also using a unique structure for sparse)

Comment: I just want to put forward std::map<std::pair<row,column>,value>.

Comment: This question is actually a heavily researched area in order to keep access speed (and low cache misses) but keep memory down. See the various [sparse storage schemes here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Storing_a_sparse_matrix). It really depends on your matrix. Is it symmetric? What is the band-width? Can you reorder it? etc. One of the more popular due to being simple to code but very performant is the [Yale storage scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Yale) aka the "truly sparse storage scheme"

Comment: @CoryKramer the elements seem to represent a position of a car. Cars can move. Symmetry does not seem likely ....

Comment: I'm not well-educated in this field, I'm just curious—for "the problem of finding what's in the next position," what's wrong with just looking up a pair in a map as @user2672165 suggests?

Comment: I would avoid the polymorphic approach and consider two (possibly sorted) *vectors* each containing just the coordinates.

Comment: @user2672165 probably your suggestion can be useful...does the map put each pair<row-col,value> on the heap like a vector?

Comment: @CoryKramer I don't have any information about the matrix, I'll look for the Yale storage scheme you said

Comment: @UmNyobe I know the size of the matrix only when I read the file, so at runtime

Comment: Not exactly. map is more optimized for insertion/deletion compared to a sorted vector, but yes on the heap but not contiguous in memory as a vector. If you only have a few cars the vector does not need to be sorted for fast lookup. It could be a simple start using a map. You could also take a brief look at a spatial index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply create a [memory mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) directly over the file? (assuming your data 0,1,2 is stored in contiguous bytes (or bits) in the file, and the position of those bytes also represents the coordinates of the cars)

This way you don't need to allocate extra memory and read in all the data, and the data can simply and efficiently be accessed with `M[i][j]`.

Going over the rows would be L1-cache friendly.

In case of very sparse data, you could scan through the data once and keep a list of the empty regions/blocks in memory (only need to store startpos and size), which you could then skip (and adjust where needed) in further runs.

With memory mapping, only frequently accessed pages are kept in memory. This means that once you have scanned for the empty regions, memory will only be allocated for the frequently accessed non-empty regions (all this will be done automagically by the kernel - no need to keep track of it yourself).

Another benefit is that you are accessing the OS disk cache directly. Thus no need to keep copying and moving data between kernel space and user space.

To further optimize space- and memory usage, the cars could be stored in 2 bits in the file.

**Update**:

> I'll have to move cars with openMP and MPI... Will the memory mapping
>   work also with concurrent threads?

You could certainly use multithreading, but not sure if openMP would be the best solution here, because if you work on different parts of the data at the same time, you may need to check some overlapping regions (i.e. a car could move from one block to another).

Or you could let the threads work on the middle parts of the blocks, and then start other threads to do the boundaries (with red cars that would be one byte, with blue cars a full row).

You would also need a locking mechanism for adjusting the list of the sparse regions. I think the best way would be to launch separate threads (depending on the size of the data of course).

Comment: I've not specified that in the next step I'll have to move cars with openMP and MPI... Will the memory mapping work also with concurrent threads?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion... it can resolve both dense and sparse case with one implementation, but even if you say "simply" I can't find useful example on the web on how to do it. The only one is this: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2044.html#ClassFileMappingMembers
(I'm new to C++)

Comment: @rh0x - Indeed, only one implementation needed for both cases. With memory mapping you create a 'mapped view' over the file, and once created you can access the data as if it were memory (with pointers, or [] etc.) - For Linux check out [mmap()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), for Windows [CreateFileMapping()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537.aspx) - It isn't as hard as it looks, and can be very powerful/fast.

Comment: Regarding the openMP and MPI, it's compulsory to use both because the professor wants that we know them! I'll look for mmap thank you

Comment: @rh0x - Well.. openMP is mostly used around loops and other small blocks of code where the data can easily be split up in independent parts (and where it is easy to quickly introduce multiple threads without a lot of code). In this case data can be 'moved' across blocks, so if it could be done with openMP it would at least need some special coding. To learn openMP, other examples might be better suited. (also wondering: how big will the data be?)

Comment: I have to iterate with a nested for-for loop to access the matrix cells, so I think openMP can be used. For example for the red car I'll have a nested for(row)-for(col), for blue ones a nested for(col)-for(row). Moreover I found an example with openMP + mmap() here: http://beej.us/blog/data/parallel-programming-openmp/ (source code at the end of the page)

Comment: @rh0x - Ok, but make sure you take care of [Data dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dependency) - for example, thread B starts at pos 1000, while thread A moves a car from pos 980 to 1020 - or the other way around.

Comment: I thought to something like: 
Red-turn --> 1 thread per row
Blue-turn --> 1 thread per column
If I understand correctly what you said for 'data dependency' I can have this problem when I cannot map the whole file in memory... is it right?

Comment: @rh0x - That would be way too many threads. Plus, Blue-turn (thread per column) would be bad for L1 cache - only one byte read every full row. I'll update the answer with some more details tomorrow. Are the cars stored as bytes in the file? And how big can those files be? (there's a difference in algorithm for a few kB or a few GB).

Comment: 1. Yes every car is a byte in the file and they are comma separated.
2. Those files are < 1GB

Answer (score 1):

In a somewhat similar task, I simply made use of [Compressed Row Storage](http://netlib.org/linalg/html_templates/node91.html#SECTION00931100000000000000).

> The Compressed Row and Column (in the next section) Storage formats
>   are the most general: they make absolutely no assumptions about the
>   sparsity structure of the matrix, and they don't store any unnecessary
>   elements. On the other hand, they are not very efficient, needing an
>   indirect addressing step for every single scalar operation in a
>   matrix-vector product or preconditioner solve.

You will need to be a bit more specific about time and space complexity requirements. CSR requires an extra indexing step for simple operations, but that is a minor amount of overhead if you're just doing simple matrix operations.

[There's already an existing C++ implementation available online as well.](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/8352/)

Comment: Could be interesting for read-only data, but what would the performance be with removals/insertions? (i.e. moving cars)

Comment: @Danny_ds From the wiki article: ` This format is efficient for arithmetic operations, row slicing, and matrix-vector products.` With that being said, simple logic operations (ie: set/unset a flag/bitfield/status) would also be comparatively quickl. Also, storage savings are considerable.