# Parallelization false sharing Openmp

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a matrix of integers, for example:

```
1 0 1
2 1 0
1 1 1
```

This is a trivial example; my problem is much larger than this example (think 2000 x 2000). I have to modify the matrix following this rules: I have to do two steps: (1) If the element below a `1` in my matrix is 0, then my move should be `"1"`, and then (2) if the element to the right of a `2` in my matrix is 0, my move should be `"2"`.

I'm using two vectors to save the positions of ones and twos. These vectors are `std::vector<triplet>` where triplet is a `struct` made to handle the problem:

```
struct triplet{
    int row, column, move;
};
```

So each element of `vector1` contains the position of 1 (row and column) and the variable move (that is 0 or 1) to show me if I can move the associated 1.
I do the same with vector 2 separately.

```
void modifyvector1(vector<vector<int>>& matrix,vector<triplet>& vector1,int nrow,int ncolumn)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int scorriblu = 0; scorriblu < vector1.size(); scorriblu++) {

        int i = vector1[scorriblu].row;
        int j = vector1[scorriblu].column;
        vector1[scorriblu].move = 0;

        if(i != nrow) {
            if (matrix[i+1][j] == EmptySpace) {
                vector1[scorriblu].move = 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (matrix[0][j] == EmptySpace) {
                vector1[scorriblu].move = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, this program is slower than serial. I think that the main problem is that each thread is trying to access the matrix that is stored in shared memory and this is causing a huge rallenty. But I am not sure that this is the problem, and how to fix it.

Sorry for my explanation but I'm new with C++ and OpenMP.

Comment: Here is a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591861/efficient-time-and-space-complexity-data-structure-for-dense-and-sparse-matrix/34592310#34592310).

Comment: Yes but that question is very far from my problem... I don't understand how can i solve my problem without change the way i handle the matrix moviment. I would still use vector that maps the matrix ,and try to parallelize my code

Comment: Actually, it's exactly the same [question (updated link to point to the main question)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591861/efficient-time-and-space-complexity-data-structure-for-dense-and-sparse-matrix). Are you forced to use OpenMP? No need to use 2 vectors, even 1 vector with 3 int's wastes a lot of space. Those 0,1,2 could be stored in a single byte (or even 2 bits if necessary).

Comment: No it's not the same question.I have the same problem but with a different and easier question.I think that your advice (use mmap() ) explained in the other 3d is useful but too complex.So i decided to use these vectors, and my only question is why my piece of program is slower with OpenMp than serial .In that i don't modify the matrix ( i only want to change the vector1.move)

Comment: You don't have to use `mmap()` here (only 2000*2000). But mmap is not complex at all, it would even be simpler than the code provided. There's no need to use 2 vectors with int triplets, just store each value in a byte and loop over them. Should take less than 1ms. There's not really a need for parallelization in this case.

Comment: It's a project that i have to do for my course, i made that in my way,so i asked here a question about a parallelization problem,not about how to face the problem.So if you can help me about that :)

Comment: @Federico I just edited your program for typos and improved the grammar of your overall question. Can you confirm that using `ncolumn` was a typo? Did you run this exact program and verify that you got correct results?

Comment: As to why this is slower in parallel than in sequential, it is because your data is simply not big enough. With a 2000 x 2000 matrix, with only a subset of them being `1`, your `vector1.size()` is probably on the order of 100000. Usually you only want to parallelize when you have significantly more computations per iteration or significantly more iterations. Finally, please ensure you are calculating elapsed time using `omp_get_wtime()` and not `clock()`. The first will show wall time, the second will show cpu time (not helpful when measuring parallelization).

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll Yes sorry i made a mistake about ncolumn,now it's right.My problem is that with a matrix of 2000*2000 the omptime  is at least two time slower than serial.And i semplificate the problem here, in my program i have a vector of "2" with coordinates. But i'm sure that at most  parallelization time is the same of serial time. Thank you for the help, i'm in a terrible situation

Comment: @Federico What is your `vector1.size()`? And again, are you sure you're timing the program with `omp_get_wtime()`?

Comment: It's 200000 element; I tried with omp_get_wtime() and in serial version the program spends 30 seconds,with omp 20 seconds;that it's very good,but if i want compare the serial version with OpenOmp version,can i use for the  serial version :clock(),end and time=((double)(end-start))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; and your way with OpenMP?

Comment: From wikipedia: "For programs executed in parallel, the CPU time will be the sum of CPU times devoted to the task by each CPU running it. In this case the wall time will be substantially reduced (it takes less perceived time to finish), whereas the total CPU time will remain equal to the one for serial execution (plus some overhead for parallelization)." `clock()` returns CPU time (which in serial is roughly equivalent to wall time). `omp_get_wtime()` returns actual wall time.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll thank you!! Do you think that i can not improve my parallelization of this for ?